# Facebook comment plugin loads only at some pages

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

There are two pages of the website - facebook comment plugin scripts seem to be identical, page source also shows that both should work ok, but somehow under this url http://fonovit.at/fonovitplnew/bol-plecow.html facebook comment box is appearaing, but under for example this http://fonovit.at/fonovitplnew/przepuklina-kregoslupa.html it does not.

I am totally lost and have not a single why it works at some and does in similarly the same situation.

thank you for all the help!

Comment: I have checked other discussions on the subject, but none of the solutions offered seem to work. Maybe there is some obvious mistake which I constantly overlook, but whole day of research did not help to find a solution

Comment: Same problem in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem on Facebook's site. Comments don't appear on my site for articles newer than the 15th ... So the script works, just not for new articles. It so appears that they're just not loaded today... (?!)

**Update:** FB is deploying a fix, I figure this should solve most problems like this one

Comment: Indeed it seems to be issue on fb side. Everything seems to work now.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem with my site, with the FB comment widget not loading for ~50% of pages despite everything being identical and working fine until today, for 2+ years. This seems to have started around 1AM GMT. FB Graph (http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=[URL]) is returning a blank "data" array for the affected pages too.

It looks like an issue on the FB side, I cannot come up with any other possible explanations. No reason for the script to break on some pages but not others when no changes have been made.

[EDIT] Open the FB moderation tool and check the sorting order (Sort Comments By) - is it set to Top by any chance? If so, try changing it to Newest or Oldest - this is how I fixed an identical issue on my site.